# I need to verify only Sending Domain and API Key

Tags: curl, sparkpost

I need to verify only the Sending Domain and the API key. Now I use this curl:

```
curl \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: <REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_API_KEY>" \
-X POST -d '{"options":{"open_tracking":true,"click_tracking":true},"metadata":{"some_useful_metadata":"testing_sparkpost"},"substitution_data":{"signature":"<REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_FIRST_AND_LAST_NAME>"},"recipients":[{"address":{"email":"<REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS>"},"tags":["learning"],"substitution_data":{"customer_type":"Platinum","first_name":"<REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_FIRST_NAME>"}}],"content":{"from":{"name":"Awesome Company","email":"testing@<REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_SENDING_DOMAIN>"},"subject":"My first SparkPost Transmission","text":"Hi {{first_name}}\r\nYou have just sent your first email through SparkPost!\r\nCongratulations,\r\n{{signature}}","html":"<strong>Hi {{first_name}},</strong><p>You have just sent your first email through SparkPost!</p><p>Congratulations!</p>{{signature}}"}}' \
https://api.sparkpost.com/api/v1/transmissions
```

This url sends me an email so it is correct, but I must use a url that doesn't send email but verify the correctness of API key and the Sending domain. Anyone can help me?

Comment: I'm sorry. What are you trying to do? We do have a Sending Domains API.

Comment: I need to verify if the API Key and the Sending domain email is correct without send an email is it possibile or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to verify two things:

1. that your API Key is able to send a transmission (an email)
2. that you are able to send using your Sending domain

To do that you can use the same cURL command as you have in your question, but append `.sink.sparkpostmail.com` to the end of your domain. That will return a 200 if your API key and sending domain are correct but will not send an email (however that send will still count against your usage). You can read more about the sinkhole [here](https://support.sparkpost.com/customer/portal/articles/2361300-how-to-test-integrations).

Alternately, you can use [the Sending Domains page](https://app.sparkpost.com/account/sending-domains) or [Sending Domains API](https://developers.sparkpost.com/api/sending-domains#sending-domains-retrieve,-update,-and-delete-get) to see the status of your domain. You can use [the Credentials page](https://app.sparkpost.com/account/credentials) to verify that your API key has the "Transmissions: Read/Write" permission